# Python code and SQLite3 won't INSERT data in table Pycharm?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pycharm

What am I doing wrong here? It run's without error, it has created table, but rows are empty. Why?

[image: Full Image]

```
import sqlite3

sqlite_file = (r"C:\Users\Dragan\PycharmProjects\MyProject\ArchLib2.db")
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
cursor = conn.cursor()

table_name = 'Archive'

sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + table_name + '("first_name" varchar NOT NULL, "second_name" varchar NOT NULL)'
cursor.execute(sql)

sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + table_name + '(first_name,second_name) VALUES ("value1","value2");'
cursor.execute(sql)

cursor.close()
```

Comment: Make sure you call `conn.commit()` after inserting your data.

Comment: I did... and nothing Table is still empty.. 3 hours wasted on this

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I found why it didn't INSERT data into table.

- data in `sql =` string didnt have good formating ( this `'` must be replaced with this `"`
- second if you have string value like `"value1"` it has to have backslash on both sides like this `"\value1\"`
- third and most important after insert execution line you have to add this line `conn.commit()`

Final code looks like this:

```
import sqlite3

sqlite_file = (r"C:\Users\Dragan\PycharmProjects\MyProject\ArchLib2.db")
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
cursor = conn.cursor()

table_name = 'Archive'

sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + table_name + "(first_name varchar NOT NULL, datetime)"
cursor.execute(sql)

sql = "INSERT INTO " + table_name + "(first_name,datetime) VALUES (\"value1\",CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"
cursor.execute(sql)

conn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Comment: wether or not you use ' or " doesn't matter: 'string' is "string" == True